# Overlay overall distribution graph with segment wise distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

age = sample(1:100,100,T)
segment = sample(1:5,100,T)

data = data.frame(age,segment)

setDT(data)[age > 0 & age < 20, agegroup := "0-19"]

data[age >19 & age <40, agegroup := "20-39"]
data[age >39 & age <60, agegroup := "40-59"]
data[age >59, agegroup := "60+"]
```

I want to represent the age distribution overall and segment wise.

[image]

The dotted lines is the overall distribution and each segment wise so that I can compare how is the segment and overall distribution. how to overlay two plots in one graph?

Comment: can you please show the code that you are trying

Comment: Please go through to understand how to draw `ggplot` - http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Thanks for quick response. i have tried this 
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = agegroup, y = segment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
but im stucked  to overlay the two plots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create additional dataset for the overall distribution, merge them and plot with different `geom_bar`'s.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(data.table)

# Using OPs data
data <- data[, .N, .(segment, agegroup)]
data2 <- data[, sum(N), .(agegroup)]
data3 <- merge(data, data2)


data3 <- merge(data3, data3[, .(MAX = max(N)), segment], "segment")

ggplot(data3, aes(agegroup)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = V1),
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
             color = "black", fill = "white",
             linetype = 2) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = N, fill = N == MAX),
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
             width = 0.6, color = "black") +
    facet_wrap(~ segment) +
    labs(x = "Age group",
         y = "Number of observations") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "grey5")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. can you please suggest is there any better way to represent this kind of data? comparing segments with overall data? after looking the graph its not convincing. or can you please tell me how to highlight the agegroup with most observations in each segment. example in segment 1 60+ needs to highlight with other color or bold in segment 4 agegroup 20-39 like that and also i wanted dotted line needs to change to normal line

Comment: @KalyanKumar Actually I like how data is presented here (as x-axis is categorical bars is the only way to present it). You can change normal line with `linetype` option.

Comment: Thanks. how about the percentages/proportions instead of numbers? can you please include the percentages.

Comment: @KalyanKumar Sorry, but it's hard to understand what you want and sounds like a new question

Comment: Thanks. I got the percentage thing i just wanted to check can we heightlight the bars with chronological order instead of only max value? so max value bar will get dark color then light color so on and can we change all the segments in only one row itself instead of 2 rows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ggplot` like this

```
windows()
ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=data, aes(x=agegroup, y=age), stat = "identity", fill = "red") + # Overall plot
geom_bar(data=data[segment == 2,], aes(x=agegroup, y=age), stat = "identity", , fill = "blue") # segment 1
```